Allure property allure.serve.host is not working
I have a java project for api and end-to-end ui testing and right now I am changing my reports from Serenity to Allure. I've setup the serve goal in my maven verify phase and it works fine, but Allure serves the report in a weird IP address by default, and it happens to be an address that I can't use on my work machine, so I need to change it to localhost.
I can do that by running Allure command in powershell with allure serve -h localhost, but I would very much like to be able to do this using the allure.properties file. In this file I can setup the allure.results.directory property normally, but it is ignoring the allure.serve.host and the allure.serve.port properties. I've tried also to configure this in the pom.xml file but no success.
What am I missing here? Is there a way to do what I want in this case?
Details about my project: my OS is Windows 10 Pro, I'm using Java 17, test frameworks are JUnit 5 and Cucumber 7. Allure dependency version: 2.29.1, allure standalone executable version: 2.32.0.
